# Python\Pandas\DataFrame\CSV file: issue with csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, read.csv

I'm a beginner in python programming. I was doing a school project with pandas with csv file and when I print the table it shows
[not the result I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTl32.png)

This is the actual csv file i created
[csv file i created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3eXV.png)

I hope anyone can help me with this.

Comment: share code so we can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To conveniently print your table, use the methods for setting the output format - `set_option ()`, for example, to remove the restriction on the number of columns -
`pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)`.
If you are using a development environment, then it is better to put a breakpoint on pass and run in debug mode. In pycharm, in the variable area, you can click on ...View as DataFrame and a color readable table will appear.

Comment: Thankyou for helping me it really worked.It is my first time being here :3

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't have your data, I provide my suggestion for you by following two points.

1.Clean and set your csv file like this form - first row is header and rest of them are data.

2.Use this code to import your csv file. (skip the first row from your csv file)

[pandas read csv where csv's col names are in second row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482253/pandas-read-csv-where-csvs-col-names-are-in-second-row)

Please let me know if you still have any question

Thanks
Leon

Comment: Thanks for commenting, i have successfully solved the isssue :3